# Laravel fill option values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm currently working on a project with a search function. I'm getting some data from my database. I bind this data through my controller. And fill my dropdownlist with it, including a default select item. Is it possible to set the values from the select to the data I retrieve from my database?

// Browser

```
<select id="game_kind" name="game_kind">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Make your choice..</option>
      <option value="1">puzzle</option>
      <option value="4">dice game</option>
      <option value="5">card game</option>
      <option value="6">board game</option>
 </select>
```

// Controller

```
    public function Filter()
    {
        $game_kinds = GameKind::where('game_kind_name_en','!=','')->lists('game_kind_name_en');

        return View::make('web.spelzoeken', compact('game_kinds');
    }
```

// View

```
    {{ Form::open(['route' => 'web.search.post']), PHP_EOL }}
       {{ Form::label('game_kind',Lang::get('web-zoeken.search-game'))}}
       {{ Form::select('game_kind', ['' => Lang::get('web-zoeken.search-option')] + $game_kinds)}}
       {{ Form::submit(Lang::get('web-zoeken.search-button'), ['class' => 'button tiny']), PHP_EOL }}
    {{ Form::close(), PHP_EOL }}
```

// Result I really want

```
<select id="game_kind" name="game_kind">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Make your choice..</option>
      <option value="puzzle">puzzle</option>
      <option value="dice game">dice game</option>
      <option value="card game">card game</option>
      <option value="board game">board game</option>
 </select>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Solution: $game_kinds = GameKind::where('game_kind_name_en','!=','')->lists('game_kind_name_en','game_kind_name_en'); The second parameter in lists defines the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
$game_kinds = GameKind::where('game_kind_name_en','!=','')
    ->lists('game_kind_name_en');
```

into this:

```
// SELECT 'field' AS 'alias' ...
$game_kinds = GameKind::select('game_kind_name_en', 'game_kind_name_en as game_kind_name_en_key') 
    ->where('game_kind_name_en','!=','')
    ->lists('game_kind_name_en', 'game_kind_name_en_key');
```

**From the docs:**

> Specifying A Select Clause
>
> $users = DB::table('users')->select('name as user_name')->get();

or `...->lists(...)` in your case

And

> Retrieving A List Of Column Values
>
> $roles = DB::table('roles')->lists('title');
>
> This method will return
>   an array of role titles. You may also specify a custom key column for
>   the returned array:
>
> $roles = DB::table('roles')->lists('title', 'name');

---

BTW

**- Don't use spaces in HTML-attribute names.**

Instead of doing:

`value="dice game"`

Do like:

`value="dice_game"`.

Comment: That didn't make any difference, I believe I need to redefine my blade injection. Thanks for the fast reply though.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't change anything for me. Isn't there a way to manually set the keys and values in the blade injection? Perhaps I can change the values through Javascript, then my problem might be solved, but I'd like to avoid that way.

Comment: what do you get if you do a `->get()`instead of a `->lists()` with my query. adda a `dd($game_kinds)` after the get()... cause your view looks ok

Comment: @Jorn See edit I took the select first, and as second the where, from one of my projects, so if there is anything in $game_kinds, this should work

Comment: Well I did something really stupid, was adapting my code in the wrong function so it never adjusted in my browser. My problem is fixed with the select query, many thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that! Thx for accepting my anser.   After all that work, would you mind eventually upvote my answer too?

Comment: I need 15 reputation for that, will do when I have it.